# joomla modal popup does not closing properly in IE

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

joomla modal popup plugin does not closing properly in IE, but In FF browser, plugin is awesome.

when i click the close button. looks its closing. but actually it is not closing. that light box is displaying browser below with just blank. please find the attached screen shot fyr.[image]

Note: in the attached screen shot popup will coming down(footer area) after user clicked the close icon in the light box.

```
echo '<td><a class="modal" href="modules/mod_popupdetails/showdetails_popup.php?qs='.$row->$somthing.'" rel="{handler: \'iframe\', size: {x:1040 , y: 500}}" >Table</a></td>';
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you running?  Are you in compatibility mode?

Comment: IE8, yes compatibility mode

Comment: Try turning OFF compatibility mode (yuck!) and update your IE to 9+.  If you're running IE8, and compatibility mode - a lot of things will break.

Comment: when i do this, that time light box working. but i am expecting when browser loading that time itself popup should come correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as your comment states, if turning off compatibility mode fixes it - then your issue lies in compatibility with older versions of IE.  You can either try to find a workaround for that - or just design for newer versions.  There really are very few people who use older versions of IE anymore - so I would recommend perhaps checking their browser version and asking them to upgrade, instead of trying to find some ugly hack/workaround for those few people.  May not be 'best practice', but it works.

Comment: i too believe this is reason, as well when i test with best compatible view its working fine. but how to make while page loading itself.